# Обрезать фото с камеры

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь обрезать фото после снимка с камеры и загрузить его в `ImageView`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, Consts.ACTION_PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


  switch (requestCode) {
        case Consts.ACTION_PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            if ((data != null) && (data.getExtras() != null)) {
                testURI = data.getData();
                crop();
        case Consts.ACTION_CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); //вот тут NPE
                Bitmap pic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                setEventImage(pic, "dd");
```

**Вот тут обрезаем:**

```
private void crop() {
        try {
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(testURI, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, Consts.ACTION_CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
```

**Получаю**  `NPE`:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a
>   null object reference

Использовал вот [этот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/photocamera.php) пример

Answer (score 2):

В extras вы не сможете получить полное изображение. Максимум - маленький preview, и то не всегда. Чтобы получить полное изображение, вам нужно в интент передать параметр "путь изображения для сохранения":

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Где `file` = файл, в который нужно записать изображение.

И дальше в `onActivityResult`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), new BitmapFactory.Options());
```

Comment: Спасибо, это частично помогло. На некоторых девайсах (с апи<21) работает, но на 21+ апи ошибка Google фото. В прочем, наверное это уже другая история

Comment: да,  абсолютно на всех устройствах 21+ API вылетает ошибка Google фото.

Comment: @nonews, а на каких устройствах вы пробовали?

Comment: NPE пропал во всех версиях.
Ошибку гугл фото наблюдал на:
ASUS Max, Android 5.1.
Nexus 6, Android 7.

На 4-ках этой ошибки нет.